# Displaying flot PieChart from asp.net mvc json data

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, flot, pie-chart

flot chart fails to display .  There are no errors popping up when debugging. but same js display data for a sparkline chart. the data is in json format and looks like this. ..

```html
[
  {
    "label": "Female",
    "data": 43
  },
  {
    "label": "Male",
    "data": 56
  }
]
```

while the actual js is like this ...

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').addClass('light-navbar');
            $.getJSON("../../Dashboard/getGuestGenderPieData")
            .done(function (data) {
                jQuery('#guestgenderpie').sparkline(data, {
                   type: 'pie',
                   height: '140',
                   sliceColors: ['#1ab394', '#F5F5F5']
            })
        });
    });        
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, that's rough. "Here's some code that works but doesn't use Flot, however I'm not going to show you the code that does use Flot and that doesn't work". So ... my comment can only be "you are not passing the data in the right format to Flot".

Comment: thanks jm, a thorough look shows i'm not passing the right data.

Answer (score 0):

Sparkline pie charts accepts data in the form at [24, 43, 33]. where each item in this array is a slice of the pie chart.
if you must send data in the initial format, then you should use a flot pie chart and not a sparkline like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.plot($("#guestgenderpie"), data, {
         series: {
            pie: {
                show: true
            }
         },
         legend: {
            labelBoxBorderColor: "none"
         }
    });
});
```

See more options at [Flot pie charts](http://www.pikemere.co.uk/blog/flot-how-to-create-pie-charts/)